# Can an app change its name and UI for one locale only?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app that's used internationally.

The app is used internationally. however, recent legal problems force me to change its name in the U.S. alone. I don't want to change it globally.

Whta's the minimal set of action I can take to get there as fast as I can?

Can I change the application name and some of its UI for a certain locale only? (ENG-US) do must I deploy a new app altogether alongside the old one? Note I must keep the "british" locale with the old UI, but myst rename the application name and change some of its ui only for the U.S.

Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whta's the minimal set of action I can take to get there as fast as I can?

In terms of the app itself:

Step #1: Find out how you are setting the name in the app. Frequently, that's via an `@string/app_name` resource, as the `android:name` in `<application>` (and perhaps also in one or more `<activity>` elements) in the manifest.

Step #2: Create alternative versions of that string resource for other languages.

Comment: do doing that I will not have to have another application in google-play, the name would simply come from the different locale?

Comment: @RM1970: I can't answer that, sorry.